# What is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_1 a_2...a_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be defined as follows:
>
> $a_1>0, a_{n+1}=\ln \dfrac{e^{a_n}-1}{a_n}$ for $n \geq 1.$ Then find the sum $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_1a_2...a_n.$

Please give some hints to solve this.

At the question it was also given that $\{a_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence of positive terms converging to 0.

Comment: Asymptotically it seems that $a_{n+1}\sim \frac{a_n}2$ not sure if it helps

Comment: @kingW3 I think $a_{n+1} \sim a_n$. But much better approximated by $a_n-\ln a_n$.

Comment: @Milten No, try $a_n=0.01$ neither $a_{n+1}-a_n$ nor $a_{n+1}-(a_n-\ln(a_n))$ is close to $0$

Comment: @kingW3 Oh, I see you meant for small values. I meant for large values.

Comment: @kingW3 You are of course right, since the sequence converges to $0$. Sorry.

Comment: Try computing this numerically for $a_1 = 1$; you may be led to a conjecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's denote $l(x)=\ln\big((e^x-1)/x\big)$, with $l(0)=0$ understood as a limit. Clearly, $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing, hence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists and is equal to $0$, the only root of $a=l(a)$. This, together with $l(x)\sim x/2$ for small $x$, implies the convergence of the sum; let it be $f(x)$, where $x=a_1$. The convergence is uniform w.r.t. $x$ in any finite range (since $l(x)$ is increasing), hence $f(x)$ is continuous. From the definition, we have $f(x)=x\big[1+f\big(l(x)\big)\big]$; substituting $f(x)=e^x-1+g(x)$, we obtain $g(x)=xg\big(l(x)\big)$. By induction, $$g(a_1)=a_1 g(a_2)=\ldots=a_1 a_2\cdots a_ng(a_{n+1}),$$ and since the RHS tends to $0$ when $n\to\infty$, we have $g(x)=0$ identically.

Finally, the answer is $e^{a_1}-1$.

Comment: The method is nice in that could be used to construct/solve similar problems. For example (for the trivial case) $\ell(x) = x$ then we can also solve $f(x) = x(1 + f(\ell(x))$ to find the solution $\frac{x}{1-x}$ (which would be a very complicated way of solving $x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots$). Would be interesting to see if there exists other non-trivial pairs $\ell(x),f(x)$ here.

Comment: @Winther: (Ah, it is trivial.) Just replace $e^x$ and $\ln x$ with a similar pair of functions (inverse to each other, mapping $1\leftrightarrow 0$, etc.).

Comment: Ah very nice! That's the general result I was hoping existed here. Let $h$ be any function that satisfy $h(x) = 1 + x + bx^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$ close to $x=0$ with $|b|<1$ and define $a_{n+1} = h^{-1}\left(\frac{h(a_n)-1}{a_n}\right)$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n a_k = h(a_1) - 1$.