# Find the sum $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}a_1a_2a_3...a_n $ where $a_{n+1}=\ln\frac{e^{a_n}-1}{a_n}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\} $ be defined as follows: 
$a_1 \gt 0$ and $$a_{n+1}=\ln\frac{e^{a_n}-1}{a_n}$$  for $n\ge 1.$

Then the sum 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_1a_2...a_n $$
is _____________

My attempt:(By using hint )

By Given condition

$a_{n+1}-a_n=\ln\frac{e^{a_n}-1}{a_n}-lne^{a_n} $

$\Rightarrow a_{n+1}-a_n=\ln\frac{1-e^{-a_n}}{a_n}       
\quad    (1) $

Now $e^x \gt 1+x \space \forall x \in R \quad (2)$

$\Rightarrow  e^{-a_n} \gt 1-a_n $

From (1)

$ a_{n+1}-a_n \lt \ln\frac{1-1+a_n}{a_n}=0  $

Also $a_{n+1} \gt \ln \frac{a_n}{a_n}=0 $ using (2) for $x=a_n$

So $\{a_n\} $ is a nonotone decreasing sequence bounded below.

Let $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=l $. Then by the given recurrence relation

$l=\ln \frac{e^l-1}{l} $

$\Rightarrow e^l(l-1)+1=0 $ is satisfied by $l=0$

Hence$ \exists k\in N$s.t $ \forall n\ge k$ ,we have $a_n \lt 1$

Let $a_1a_2...a_{k-1}=p $

Then $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}a_1a_2...a_n=p\{a_k+a_ka_{k+1}+...\} $

$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=k}^{\infty}a_1a_2...a_n \lt p\{a_k+a_k^2+...\}$ since $a_n$ is monotone decreasing .

$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=k}^{\infty}a_1a_2...a_n \lt p \frac{a_k}{1-a_k} $

So

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_1a_2...a_n \lt S+p\frac{a_k}{1-a_k} $

where $ S=\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}a_1a_2...a_n $

So the given sereis is convergent.

I would like to know if my workings are correct.I don't know how to find the actual sum.Also I have seen an answer here  ([What is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_1 a_2...a_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3417704/710290)) but unfortunately I can't understand it.Please help me in finding the sum.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about $f(x)=e^x-1$. Show that the sum is $f(a_1)$

Comment: *Hint:* Write $p_n = a_1\cdots a_n$. Then we have $$p_n = p_n e^{a_{n+1}} - p_{n+1}e^{a_{n+2}}.$$ Now invoke the idea of telescoping.

Comment: @SangchulLee..Thanks sir for the idea but I got the following problem $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k=p_1 e^{a_2}-p_{n+1}e^{a_{n+2}} $ . Now what to write $ lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } p_{n+1} $ ? .Please help with this part .

Comment: Ah ..I have got it . The limit is obviously zero , so silly of me . Well once again, thank sir .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for
$$
f(x)=e^x-1\tag1
$$
we have
$$
f(x)=x+xf\left(\log\left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right)\right)\tag2
$$
Let
$$
a_{k+1}=\log\left(\frac{e^{a_k}-1}{a_k}\right)\tag3
$$
**Identity:**

> $$
> f(a_1)
> =\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^ka_j+f(a_{n+1})\prod_{j=1}^na_j\tag4
> $$

**Proof:** Induction. It is trivially true for $n=0$. Suppose it is true for some $n$.
$$
\begin{align}
f(a_1)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^ka_j+f(a_{n+1})\prod_{j=1}^na_j\tag{5a}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^ka_j+(a_{n+1}+a_{n+1}f(a_{n+2}))\prod_{j=1}^na_j\tag{5b}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^ka_j+a_{n+1}\prod_{j=1}^na_j+a_{n+1}f(a_{n+2})\prod_{j=1}^na_j\tag{5c}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^ka_j+\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}a_j+f(a_{n+2})\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}a_j\tag{5d}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\prod_{j=1}^ka_j+f(a_{n+2})\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}a_j\tag{5e}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a)}$: inductive hypothesis
$\text{(5b)}$: apply $(2)$ and $(3)$
$\text{(5c)}$: distributive property
$\text{(5d)}$: collect $a_{n+1}$ into the products
$\text{(5e)}$: collect the product into the sum

Thus, it is true for $n+1$.

$\large\square$

The Mean Value Theorem says that there is a $\xi$ strictly between $0$ and $x$ so that
$$
e^\xi=\frac{e^x-1}x\tag6
$$
That is, $\log\left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right)$ is strictly between $0$ and $x$. Thus, $a_{k+1}$ is strictly between $0$ and $a_k$. Thus, $a=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}a_k$ exists and satisfies $a=\log\left(\frac{e^a-1}a\right)$, but this can only happen if $a=0$.

Therefore, $a_k$ tends monotonically to $0$. Thus, we can take the limit of $(4)$ to get
$$
f(a_1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n a_k\tag7
$$

Comment: ..Wow !! Brilliant proof , sir . Took me sometime to digest but feel happy to understand it. Thank you very much.