# Convergence of sum $1+c_1(1+c_2..$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I was working on an exercise and I encountered this

$1 + c_1(1+c_2(1+c_3(1 + ...$

$0<c_i<1$

Now for some reason I feel like I recognize this from something I've watched or read but I looked all over and I can't find anything like it, does this converge to anything meaningful? Or does some version of this converge to something? (If each $c_i$ is constant for example)

Comment: Notice that it's equivalent to
$$
a_n = 1+c_{n-1} a_{n-1}
$$

Comment: If $c_i=c$ is constant the recurrence result is $$a_n=\frac{a_1 c^{n+1}-a_1 c^n+c^n-c}{(c-1) c}$$ as $0<c<1$ this converges to $\frac{1}{1-c}$

Comment: Yes I noticed that it reduced to this simple geometric series when c was constant after I posted so maybe that's why I recognized it.

Comment: $1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_1 c_2 \cdots c_n$ converges by the ratio test if $\limsup_{n\to \infty} c_n < 1 $. I doubt that much more can be said in the case of a general sequence $(c_n)$.

Comment: And so it converges if $c_i<C<1$ by comparison with the geometric series.

Comment: @MattiP. Not exactly. The third term of your sequence (bar some $n$ versus $n-1$ detail) is $$a_3=1+c_3(1+c_2(1+c_1))=1+c_3+c_3c_2+c_1c_2c_3$$ while it should rather be $$a_3=1+c_1(1+c_2(1+c_3))=1+c_1+c_1c_2+c_1c_2c_3$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is the infinite series
$$ 
1 + c_1 + c_1c_2 + c_1c_2c_3 + \cdots = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_1 c_2 \cdots c_n \, .
$$
As pointed out in the comments, this is a geometric series if the sequence $(c_n)$ is constant.

There are other special cases where the sum can be computed explicity, see for example [What is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_1 a_2...a_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3417704/what-is-sum-n-1-inftya-1-a-2-a-n).

Not much can be said in the general case. Of course the usual convergence criteria can be applied. For example, the ratio test tells us that the series is convergent if $ \limsup_{n\to \infty} c_n < 1$.

Setting $b_n = c_1 c_2 \cdots c_n$ we have $1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ with an arbitrary strictly decreasing positive sequence $(b_n)$, which demonstrates that the series may converge or diverge.

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out in the comments, we are interested in deciding on the convergence of $1+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (c_1 \cdots c_n)$. The ratio test guarantees convergence if $\limsup_{n\to \infty} c_n <1$, which is not necessarily true for any sequence satisfying $0 < c_i < 1$. Apart from that, if $0 < l_1 \leq c_i \leq l_2 < 1$, you can say that
$$
\dfrac{1}{1-l_1} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} l_1^n \leq1+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (c_1 \cdots c_n)\leq 1+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} l_2^n=\dfrac{1}{1-l_2}.
$$